# R cSplit only using first delimiter in string

Tags: r, concatenation, delimiter, splitstackshape

I had a long list with two columns where the I had the same string in each column in multiple rows. So I used `paste` to concatenate using `-` and then used `setDT` to return the unique set of concats with their frequency.

Now I want to reverse my concatenation.

I tried:

```
library(splitstackshape)
d5 <- cSplit(d4, 'conc', '-', 'wide')
```

However in my second column I sometimes had multiple `-`'s within the string.

To get around this I'd like cSplit to ONLY use the first `-` delimiter.

Example:

```
 conc      freq
 A-hello      4
 A-Hi-there   5
 B-HELLO      1
```

Using the above `cSplit` would return:

```
freq conc_001  conc_002  conc_003
   4        A     hello        NA
   5        A        Hi     there
   1        B     HELLO        NA
```

I would like:

```
freq conc_001  conc_002
   4        A     hello
   5        A  Hi-there
   1        B     HELLO
```

Comment: You might want to use `separate` from the "tidyr" package. I didn't design `cSplit` to conveniently handle these types of cases. With "tidyr", the approach might be something like `separate(mydf, conc, into = c("conc_001", "conc_002"), extra = "merge")`.

Comment: I suppose you could also do something silly like: `cSplit(setDT(mydf)[, conc := sub("-", "%^%&", conc)], "conc", "%^%&")` :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another idea.By using `sub` we restrict it to only change the first specified delimeter of the string. We then use `cSplit` with the new delimeter.

```
library(splitstackshape)
df$conc <- sub('-', ' ', df$conc)
cSplit(df, 'conc', ' ', 'wide')
#   freq conc_1   conc_2
#1:    4      A    hello
#2:    5      A Hi-there
#3:    1      B    HELLO
```

Comment: Thanks again Sotos! So sub only acts on the first and gsub acts on all.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, maybe not as straight forward as using the csplit function.  Performance is fairly fast with this method.

```
#Sample Data    
s<-c("A-hello", "A-Hi-there", "B-HELLO")
df<-data.frame(s)

#split the data into 2 parts and assign to new columns in the dataframe.
library(stringr)
mat  <- matrix(unlist(str_split(df$s, "-", n=2)), ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
dfnew<-as.data.frame(mat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Once the matrix "mat" is created, one can cbind the result onto your original matrix.

Comment: This also works and im guessing unlike sub and gsub having n=x allows for more complicated cases. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you could use `str_split_fixed` and avoid `matrix(unlist...` part

Comment: As per Sotos comment, this works: data.frame(str_split_fixed(df$s, "-", n=2)).  The result is the desired 2 column by n dataframe.

Comment: x<-(str_split(df$conc, "-", n=2) then y <- data.frame(x) then z <- t(y) then df1 <- data.frame(z) then df2 <- data.frame(sec=z$X1, word=z$X2) then df3 <- data.frame(sec=df2$sec, word=df2$word) worked too.